# Traversing files using for loop and performing cut command on files

Tags: loops, traversal, cut

I have four to five files of FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_01.tsv, FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_02.tsv, FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_03.tsv, FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_04.tsv, FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_05.tsv with other files in directory, now i have to perform cut operation only on FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_01.tsv to `FOTP_YYYYMMDD_001_05.tsv files. but using loop because fotp count can differ.

Comment: in linux.. for example we have 4 files of fotp and i perform this command on fotp cut -f2 -d "~" fotp_yyyymmdd_001_01.tsv | sort | uniq -c now rather then running this command for five files i want to run it in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be very difficult to help you with a question like this.  When you say cut - do you mean delete?  Move?  Also, what platform are you on?  Linux?  Windows?  Mac?

Comment: in linux.. for example we have 4 files of fotp and i perform this command on fotp cut -f2 -d "~" fotp_yyyymmdd_001_01.tsv | sort | uniq -c now rather then running this command for five files i want to run it in for loop.